# How to design multi level highway intersection

Tags: anylogic

So I am trying to design a multi-level highway system with the `Road Traffic library` in `Anylogic`. The highways have multiple levels and I am having trouble with depicting the difference in the levels of the roads in my model.
I looked at the [help](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp) content related to `RTL` specifically `Library Reference Guides` and `Tutorials` but they don't mention adding grades/inclination to a road to get a multi level system.

I apologize in advance if I missed documentation related to this. But I would like to know how to do this in `Anylogic`.

Also, there is a **Highway Junction** model available in the sample models that comes with the installation and implements an increase in the `z-value` of the roads but I am not sure how to do that when designing the road.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When You draw road Object in `RTL`, in points section of the drawn road properties panel, you can set the Z value of each point of your road. So you should use more than two points to draw your road, even if it is a straight one. This way you can easily set z value of different points of your road, and build up needed levels, grades or slope of the road.

[image]

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to do this via the designer, or do we have to set these values manually? Also, how do we preview the changes made to the Z values?

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by "via the designer" exactly, but if you mean something like setting z values by dragging points of road, it seems it's impossible because of 2D nature of AnyLogic designer. About preview, you can add a 3D window object, and view your roads 3D configuration.

P.s. It is not so important, but if you found this answer useful and acceptable, I would really be thankful if you accept the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I meant changing Z values by mouse input directly in the designer the way we do it if we want the road to be curved.