# Weird graphical glitch when drawing multi level road transport network

Tags: anylogic

Associated question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53215271/how-to-design-multi-level-highway-intersection).

I am trying to draw a multi level road transport network in `Anylogic`. This particular part of the network needs to be at a higher level than others. This is a highway with an exit:

[image: 2D Intersection]

The three roads have a z value of 100 each:

[image: Z-Values of road 1]

[image: Z-values of road 2]

[image: Z-values of road 3]

However, when I run the model, I see the 3-D rendering like so:

[image: 3D View]

[image: Another angle]

I would like them all to be raised but for some reason, they look weird.
What am I doing wrong?

> Edit 1

So I think I now understand one critical aspect of the the points and their z-positions. There is an overall z value of the road:

[image: Position]

Setting the z value for all the roads as `100` solved my issue.

So, my question now is: are the Z values of the `points` in the tables above relative to the "absolute" z-position of the road?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, my question now is: are the Z values of the points in the tables above relative to the "absolute" z-position of the road?

Yes, that is how it works. Notice that it is the same for x and y coordinates: You specify the overall x-y values for the first point of your road. Any subsequent point is relative to that, hence the first point having x= and y=0:
[image]